# MAPSTRUCT - Field mapperDTO in CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.howtodoinjava.demo.mapper.MapperDTO' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, crud, mapstruct

I'm building a crud application with the use of api rest and I'm going to use the mapstruct library but I can't. when I try to map the data returned by reading on the database with a custom object I get the following error

could you help me solve this problem? I get the following error

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field mapperDTO in com.howtodoinjava.demo.service.CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.howtodoinjava.demo.mapper.MapperDTO' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations: - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.howtodoinjava.demo.mapper.MapperDTO' in your configuration.

my files

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
      4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
            <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.10</org.projectlombok.version>
            <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>json-path</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
                <version>11.5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- lombok -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Map strunct -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- json logback -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- swagger -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Utility -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.bwaldvogel</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    <!--                    <compilerArgs> -->
    <!--                        <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</arg> -->
    <!--                    </compilerArgs> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

MapperDTO.java

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
/*Durante la compilazione, MapStruct genererà un'implementazione di questa interfaccia.*/
public interface MapperDTO {

    //MapperDTO INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MapperDTO.class);

    Customer customerDTOtoCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO);

    CustomerDTO customertoCustomerDTO(Customer customer);
}
```

ServiceImpl.java

```
@Autowired
    private MapperDTO mapperDTO;

    @Override
    public Customer getCustomerById(Integer id) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        Optional<CustomerDTO> utentiEntity = repository.findById(id);
            try {
                if (utentiEntity.isPresent()) {
                    return mapperDTO.customerDTOtoCustomer(utentiEntity.get());
                } else {
                    throw new RecordNotFoundException("No entity record exist for given id");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e ) {
                log.error(" message  " +e.getMessage(),e);
            }
            return null;
    }
```

demoapplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.howtodoinjava.demo")
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages="com.howtodoinjava.demo.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.howtodoinjava.demo.modelDTO")
@ComponentScan({"com.howtodoinjava.demo.service","com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller", "com.howtodoinjava.demo.mapper"})

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mapstruct jar is not correct otherwise it will dynamicaaaly at runtime it will convert entity to dto and dto to entity. But if You dont want to use mapstruct you can do that conversion manually By giving implemetation of methods like this.

```
@Override
public ProductDTO toProductDTO(Products products) {
    if (products == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
    productDTO.setName(products.getName());
    productDTO.setDescription(products.getDescription());
    productDTO.setPrice(products.getPrice());
    return productDTO;
}

@Override
public List<ProductDTO> toProductDTOs(List<Products> products) {

    if (products == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<ProductDTO> listproductdto = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();
    for (Products eachproducts : products) {
        listproductdto.add(toProductDTO(eachproducts));
    }
    return listproductdto;
}

@Override
public Products toProduct(ProductDTO productDTO) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (productDTO == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Products products = new Products();
    products.setName(productDTO.getName());
    products.setPrice(productDTO.getPrice());
    products.setDescription(productDTO.getDescription());
    return products;
}
```

For more details u can check my sample i also tried same example. from here[enter link description here](https://github.com/imchakreshtiwari/mapstruct)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and on compiling please check, if the map struct has generated the MapperDTOImpl class in the target

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming to this question on a later date, this is how I solved the issue:

Add `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` to the mapper class.

**To add this configuration as default**, I added the following in `build.gradle`

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
options.with {
    encoding = UTF_8.toString()
    compilerArgs = ['-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring']
}
}
```

**OR** in maven:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
            <compilerArgs>
                <compilerArg>
                    -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                </compilerArg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I hope this helps someone!